# Where can I find the connection string for a DB2 database?

Tags: db2, connectivity

I need to connect an application to my DB2 database. Both application and db are running on the same machine.

I've tried this:

```
Server=localhost:50000;Database=myDataBase;UID=myUsername;PWD=myPassword;
```

I'm getting the following error:

> CLI0124E  Invalid argument value. SQLSTATE=HY009

Am I using the wrong connection string?

**Edit**
I've also tried the following format:

```
Provider=IBMDADB2;Database=urDataBase;Hostname=urServerAddress;Protocol=TCPIP;Port=50000;
Uid=urUsername;Pwd=urPassword;
```

Same result.

Comment: are you connecting with JDBC? ODBC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application was asking for a connection string, when all it really wanted was the Database name. I'm not sure why the field is named Connection String...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you got those connection strings. [According to the documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/c0011825.html), the provider you use needs three keywords: DSN, UID, and PWD. DSN refers to the Windows data source, which you define as usual after installing the DB2 Data Server Client software.